# Wrap WSO2 Identity Server and User Management in my own custom UI using Angularjs and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, wso2

I would like to use WSO2 SSO and API Manager. However, I would like to build my own custom UI for my end users to interact with the WSO2 framework. How can this be done?

I have done some searching, and I found some WSDLs that can be used. However, I'm not sure if there are WSDLs that encapsulate all the functionality that I'm looking for i.e. (User Management, Application Management, Claims Management, etc..)

The Base WSO2 Management console UI and Dashboard UI are not appealing and I would like to enhance the use experience with a richer UI.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For me your requirement is not exactly clear. But i think you need to build some kind of application using API Manager APIs and enable SSO for that application using identity server. If you are trying to do that please follow these[1,2,3,4,5] instructions to get clear idea bout API Manager APIs. And if you need to setup SSO with external app please use this[6] document.

```
[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/WSO2+APIs
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/
[3]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/
[4]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/admin/
[5]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API
[6]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Single+Sign-On
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do realize now that my question is unclear. What I would like to do is use WSO 2 core features but I would like to wrap those features in my own management UI. I don't want to use the UI provided for the management console or for API manager. I would like to build my own UI for the WSO2 Identity Server and User Management Components.